# Problemas con calidad al hacer Zoom sobre bitmap 16x16 Visual Studio c++.net

Tags: visual-studio, c++.net

Visual studio

Estoy intentado crear una base para dibujar PixelArt, sprites etc, con un PictureBox y un bitmap 16x16 pixeles,  al hacer Zoom a la imagen con PictureBoxSizeMode(4) y al pintar sobre el se ve así

[image: Los pixeles se ven borrosos]

El código para crear el bitmap y acercar es el siguiente:

```
bitmap = gcnew Bitmap(16, 16);
    Graphics^ g = Graphics::FromImage(bitmap);
    g->Clear(Color::White);
    pictureBox1->Image = bitmap;
    pictureBox1->SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode(4);
```

Alguna idea de como solucionarlo de antemano gracias.

Comment: ¿Seguro que eso es C++? Ese `^` en `Graphics^` no es válido en C++

Comment: Al sustituir Graphics^ por Graphics me da error, ademas lo he usado en anteriores proyectos y funciona

Comment: eso es porque no estás programando en c++, o al menos no c++ nativo. Quizá sea c++.net pero en ese caso deberías utilizar las etiquetas de .net, la de c++ a secas es para el lenguaje nativo

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación no sabia que se dividía en C++ y C++/CLI

Comment: Ruben modifica las etiquetas (usa el boton [edit]) para aclarar a que lenguaje te estas refiriendo

Comment: Gracias ya esta